# A one-off action or a series of actions in the past?

Tags: grammar

I have two sentences here whose meanings are confusing to me as they are interpreted by native speakers.

**1)    "When Jack did all the shopping, he went to the cafe."**

Means: On the days that Jack did all of the shopping, he (also) went to the cafe. (a regular (repeated) action in the past)

**2) When I paid her one dollar, she answered my question.**

Means: I paid her a dollar, and (in exchange) she answered my question. (A one-off action)

Do you agree with this interpretation of the meanings? If yes, what is the factor which determines when it should be understood as a one-off action in the past (2) or a regular action in the past (1)?

On the top of that.
Some natives say that:

1)  "When Jack did all the shopping, he went to the cafe." – can be changed to (3) **"When Jack had finished all the shopping, he went to the café."** and it will mean a one-off action in the past.

Why is it not necessary to change (2) “When I paid her one dollar, she answered my question.” to (4) **“When I HAD paid her one dollar, she answered my question.”** in order to get a meaning of a one-off action?

Comment: Think about "When Jack finished all the shopping, he went to the café" and whether it suggests a single event

Comment: I have been thinking of it a lot, now I need more opinions from others. If you hint that "When Jack finished..." doesn't imply a single event then how do you explain that "When I paid her one dollar ..." means a single event? If you have a pithy explanation, I would be grateful to read it.

Comment: I think you might be starting with a faulty premise here. *"When Jack did all the shopping, he went to the cafe."* sounds to me like he did his shopping *at the cafe*, which makes no sense (I'm AmE).

Comment: This premise is not mine, but another American's. But I see what you mean. It's interesting. To add on... "The sentence was said to mean "On the days that Jack did all of the shopping, he (also) went to the cafe. "

Comment: @medica How do you understand this one? "When Jack had done all the shopping, he went to the café." Does it show a consecutive manner of the actions?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a one time action followed by another.

Comment: @medica OK. But this one "When I paid her one dollar, she answered my question." can be easily inferred as two actions followed one after the other? Right? And we don't need the Past Perfect here to make that consecutiveness clear?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18305/discussion-between-user1425-and-medica).

Comment: It would be more natural to say, "**Whenever** Jack did all the shopping, he went to the cafe **afterwards**." (Or some other variation along similar lines.) Some tweaking of your query sentence is needed to make it unambiguous, as other commenters have already implied.

Comment: Statements like these are structually ambiguous. Deciding whether they refer to repeated or one-off occurrences generally relies on context and common sense -- is it likely that it's repeated regularly? If you want to avoid ambiguity, you reword, such as using _whenever_ instead of _when_.

Answer (score 1):

In everyday constructions such as those that the OP presents, *when* may be used in either of two senses:

> on a particular occasion that

or

> on every occasion that

The sense of *when* that the speaker intends is necessarily contextual, and the meaning that a hearer attributes to the speaker's words in everyday situations may at times involve some rather subtle distinctions. Our default handling of a single past event is to use *when* plus a simple past tense, as in the OP's second example:

> When I paid her one dollar, she answered my question.

If we want to describe a recurring situation in the past, our usual tactic is to change *when* to *whenever*:

> Whenever I paid her one dollar, she answered my question.

However, the OP's first example

> When Jack did all the shopping, he went to the café.

doesn't follow this normal pattern. Here our tendency (as hearers or readers) is to understand *when* to mean "on every occasion that" (that is, "whenever") rather than "on a particular occasion that." I suspect that the reason we shift to the "whenever" understanding of *when* in this case is, in large part, that the cause-and-effect relationship between "Jack did all the shopping" and "he went to the café" is far more tenuous than the one between "when I paid her one dollar" and "she answered my question." Jack did all the shopping and then he went to the café, but the first event didn't cause the second one; instead, the second event simply followed (sequentially) the first one.

Typically when we describe an event that follows a previous event without involving a cause-and-effect connection to that prior event, we use the word *after*, not *when*. Thus we would normally describe a one-off sequence of shopping + café visit this way:

> After Jack did all the shopping, he went to the café.

Under these circumstances, the speaker's choice of *when* instead of *after* leads us to infer that the speaker has in mind a continuing pattern of behavior, rather than a one-time-only occurrence. We conclude that *when* means *whenever*.

To test this theory of how English speakers understand *when*, let's consider another example involving Jack the shopper, but this time let's tie his sequential actions more closely together. Here is the new example:

> When Jack did all the shopping, the clerk double-bagged the groceries.

Here the double-bagging follows from the shopping much more closely than the café visit in the earlier example did. Consequently a hearer may be more inclined to interpret the sentence as describing a once-only event. Indeed, if we get rid of the troublesome word *all*, a hearer is extremely likely to interpret it that way:

> When Jack did the shopping, the clerk double-bagged the groceries.

The *all* muddies the waters by implying that more than one instance of shopping is involved, which makes the "on a particular occasion that" interpretation of *when* at least a little more difficult to sustain.

From this, it follows that the presence of *all* in the original example involving Jack's shopping and the subsequent café visit may have provided a subtle but important cue to hearers that the speaker was using *when* in the sense of "whenever." The presence of *all*, combined with the weak cause-and-effect relationship between shopping and café lounging, prompts a shift in our interpretation of *when* from the default "on a particular occasion that" to the less common alternative "on every occasion that."